# Implementing Layered Approach

Tags: java, package, layer, 3-tier

I would like to create 3-tier application in Java (Swing GUI). What is the best approach for creating layering? Is it package or creating separate project and including JAR files.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by '3-tier'? A Swing client, a server-side component and a database? You should distinguish between tiers and layers...

Comment: one is the presentation layer (GUI), Business Logic Layer and Data Access Layer

Comment: You might try asking this on Programmers.SE instead. The topic is pretty broad and subjective.

Answer (score 0):

Use Java Beans and Struts which are part of Advanced Java Programming.

If you are core java programmer, then you can use object oriented approach. You can pass objects between various tiers.

Comment: Hm, Struts is a web framework, the OP asked for Swing... and what do you mean by 'Advanced Jva Programming'?

Comment: Java programming is divided into two parts: Advanced and Core. Core consists of Java basics like OOP, AWT, Swing, Applets etc. While Advanced Java Programming contains Servlets, JSP, Java Beans, Struts etc.